# Erro ao compilar uma aplicação Web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Como fazer para resolver esse problema?

Tenho uma aplicação em dot.net e ao compilar aparece essa mensagem. Eu não queria deixar que esse diretório seja padrão.

Como posso resolver? 
Alguém teria uma ideia do que pode ser feito?

> Não foi possível encontrar o arquivo 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Documentos'.

```
 protected void importar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Antes de importar o arquivo, verifica se contém o arquivo
            if (selecionarArquivo.HasFile)
            {
                // Obter o nome da planilha do excel para carregar.
                if (Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.FileName) != ".xlsx" && Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.FileName) != ".xls")
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Erro", "<script>alert('Somente arquivos em excel')</script>");

                else
                {
                    if (selecionarArquivo.FileContent != null)
                    {
                        string Excel = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + selecionarArquivo.FileName;
                        selecionarArquivo.SaveAs(Excel);
                    }

                    // Gerando uma string de conexão para o arquivo excel.
                    string strExcelConn = "@DATA SOURCE=DAPP;PASSWORD=APL_SD7#PP4;USER ID=APL_SDP";

                    DataTable dtExcel = RetrieveData(strExcelConn);

                    // Obtendo as contagens das linhas, antes de importar.
                    int iStartCount = GetRowCounts();

                    // Importar os dados.
                    SqlBulkCopyImport(dtExcel);

                    int iEndCount = GetRowCounts();


                }
            }
        }


        // Obter as contagens de linhas na tabela do SQL Server
        protected int GetRowCounts()
        {
            int iRowCount = 0;


            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["@DATA SOURCE=DAPP;PASSWORD=APL_SD7#PP4;USER ID=APL_SDP"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from SDPJ_IMPORT_PROCESSO", conn);
                conn.Open();

                // Executa o SqlCommand e obtendo as contagens da linhas.
                iRowCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }

            return iRowCount;
        }

        // Recupar dados da planilha do Excel.
        protected DataTable RetrieveData(string strConn)
        {


            DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Documentos;Persist Security Info=False;"))
            {

                // Inicializando um objeto OleDbDataAdapter.
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from sdpj_import_processo", conn);


                // Preenchendo o DataTable com dados da planilha do Excel
                da.Fill(dtExcel);
            }

            return dtExcel;
        }


        private void SqlBulkCopyImport(DataTable dtExcel)
        {

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"DATA SOURCE=DAPP;PASSWORD=APL_SD7#PP4;USER ID=APL_SDP;"].ToString()))

            //@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="" + caminho + "";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"
            {
                // Abrir conexão.
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                {
                    // Especificando o nome do destino da tabela.
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "sdpj_import_processo";

                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dtExcel.Columns)
                    {
                        // Como o numeros das colunas do excel 
                        // não é igual ao numeros de colunas da tabela, precisamos mapear as colunas.

                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.ColumnName);
                    }

                    // Escreva o destino do arquivo.
                    //Define o nome da tabela

                    //[OPTIONAL]: Mapeie as colunas do Excel com a da tabela do banco de dados 
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Data de Requisição Pgto", "DAT_REQ_PGTO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUMERO PROCESSO ANTERIOR", "NUM_PROC_ANTERIOR");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUMERO JUDICIAL", "NUM_PROC_JUDICIAL");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COMARCA", "DSC_COMARCA");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VARA", "NUM_VARA");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VARANOME", "NME_VARA");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NOME", "NME_INTERESSADO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CPF", "CPF_CNPJ_INTERESSADO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DEENDERECO", "DSC_ENDERECO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUENDERECO", "NUM_ENDERECO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NMMUNICIPIO", "NME_MUNICIPIO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DECOMPLEMENTO", "DSC_DECOMPLEMENTO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DEBAIRRO", "NME_BAIRRO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUCEP", "NUM_CEP");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NMMUNICIPIO", "NME_MUNICIPIO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BRUTO", "VLR_BRUTO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("IRPF", "VLR_IR");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("LIQUIDO", "VLR_LIQUIDO");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Nº SEP", "COD_SEP");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATA SEP", "DAT_SEP");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATA DE RECEBIMENTO NA ORIGEM", "DAT_RECEB_ORIGEM");

                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcel);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posta a parte do código que está dando o erro

Comment: protected DataTable RetrieveData(string strConn)
        {DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Documentos;Persist Security Info=False;"))
            {// Inicializando um objeto OleDbDataAdapter.
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from sdpj_import_processo", conn);// Preenchendo o DataTable com dados da planilha do Excel
                da.Fill(dtExcel);
            }return dtExcel;
        }

Comment: esta dando erro nesse código acima, nessa linha da.Fill(dtExcel);

Comment: Gostaria de ver uma forma de evitar que esse diretório seja padrão para conseguir compilar.

Comment: como está a sua strConn?

Comment: Leandro Angelo postei todo meu código referente a funcionalidade da situação de importar para melhor entender. O que você acha que pode ser?

Comment: Seu Data Source=Documentos; não foi encontrado.... altere a conexão para um caminho valido OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Documentos;Persist Security Info=False;"))

Comment: Por motivos de segurança, recomendo editar seu post e ocultar sua senha passada como parâmetro em sua string de conexão.

Comment: A senha e usuario que coloquei é fake hahaha, deixar mais padronizado :), apos a alteração ficou assim:

Comment: using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Documentos\\96- 1 Dativos;Persist Security Info=False;"))
            {

                // Inicializando um objeto OleDbDataAdapter.
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from sdpj_import_processo", conn);// Preenchendo o DataTable com dados da planilha do Excel
                da.Fill(dtExcel);
            }

            return dtExcel;

Comment: A mensagem de erro agora é: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2147467259 Message='C:\Documentos\96- 1 Dativos' não é um caminho válido. Certifique-se de que o nome do caminho esteja escrito corretamente e que você esteja conectado ao servidor